# Elements of the FirstViewController still visible in DetailViewController after using pushViewController method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I first programmatically created a tableview :

```
private func setupTableView() {
    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 180, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), style: UITableView.Style.plain)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    tableView.register(ItemTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

and set the cellForRow method as below :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell

    guard let finalItems = presenter.finalItems?[indexPath.row] else { return cell }
    presenter.configure(cell: cell, FinalItem: finalItems)

    return cell
}
```

Then I configure the ItemTableViewCell as below :

```
class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private var iconImageView : UIImageView = {
       let imgView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Image"))
       imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
       imgView.clipsToBounds = true
       return imgView
    }()

    private var titleLabel : UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.textColor = .black
        lbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        lbl.textAlignment = .left
        return lbl
    }() 

    func configure(finalItem: FinalItem) {
       titleLabel.text = finalItem.title
       iconImageView.downloaded(from: finalItem.images_url.small)
    }
}
```

When I push to the DetailViewController with the uinavigationbar, the elements contained in the rows (titles, labels...) are still visible a few milli seconds:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let finalItem = finalItems[indexPath.row]
    let detailViewController = ModuleBuilder.createDetailModuleWith(finalItem)
    detailViewController.finalItem = finalItem
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
}
```

This is not what I am expecting. I never figure this problem out before.

Comment: Did you test with Instruments what part of the code is taking time?

Comment: what is the background color of your detail view ?